# Questions about singular/plural when explaining two things in one sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence-combination

Consider the following two sentences.

1. In [10], an algorithm to find a trajectory of a UAV effective in estimating the channel models for a target area has been proposed.
2. In [11], an algorithm to find a trajectory of a UAV effective in estimating the user locations for a target area has been proposed.

With the above two sentences, I want to express them in one sentence.

> In [10] and [11], algorithms to find trajectories of a UAV effective in estimating the A2G channel models and the user locations, respectively, for target areas have been proposed.

Is it reasonable to combine my two sentences into one sentence?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to have your initial adverbial clause refer to both "10" ***and*** "11", in the cited context. But imho the text is convoluted and difficult to parse anyway, and I ***think*** it's probably "wrong" (for example, I can't make out what the word ***respectively*** is supposed to be referring to).

Comment: Belay that! I hadn't noticed how little of the text is the same in each example. It's far to complex to combine, being already difficult to parse even as two separate sentences!

Comment: I assume the change from "channel models" to "channel parameters" was unintentional?

Comment: @AndyBonner Ah, it is a typo. I changed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [10] is the one for finding an optimal UAV trajectory solution that minimize the error of the channel estimation. [11] is the one for finding an optimal UAV trajectory solution that minimize the error of the location estimation. I just wanted to merge them in one sentence.

Comment: One important question is: *why*? I presume the answer is "to reduce repetition and make the writing more efficient." This is a way that engineers often look at code or materials, but it's even more important to remember that *efficient* writing *communicates* efficiently. Sometimes we can make it better by reducing the number of words, but sometimes we actually make it less clear.

Comment: What @AndyBonner said. But all that is just general-purpose "style advice". There are some genuine *syntactic* issues here (should ***for the target area*** be pluralised, for example?), but they're really a bit of a side issue in such "tricky" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can merge two sentences, and you can use "respectively" to help clarify what refers to what. (*Tom and Jane like burgers and hot dogs, respectively.*)
2. These sentences are already long and complex enough that, instead, they would probably benefit from a different structure.

It would read a bit more easily if you move the main verbal phrase higher in the sentence:

> In [10] and [11], algorithms have been proposed to find trajectories of a UAV effective in estimating the channel models and user locations (respectively) for a target area.

... But that's still awfully hard to parse. Something like this might be easier:

> In [10] and [11], I propose* algorithms to find trajectories of a UAV. The [10] algorithm can help make effective estimates of the channel models for a target area, and the [11] algorithm can be similarly effective for user locations.

* If you're forced to use the passive voice ("algorithms have been proposed") by a style guide or other factors, then you'll have to do so; otherwise, active voice is much more readable and interesting. I've made the assumption that the correct pronoun is "I"; that might not be true. Also, I understand little enough about the source material that I might be mangling the intended meaning overall.